# generate an autocomplete combobox in jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I have the code as

```
<select id="select1" style="display:none">
   <option value="Java">Java</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
   <option value="C++">C++<option>
</select>

$(function(){
   $('#select1').combobox();
});
```

However, this does not work  and i get the error

```
undefined is not a function evaluating $.combobox();
```

What are the file required to be included for this.

I am using jQuery UI.

Comment: Look here : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: could be  a number of reasons...forgot to include jQueryUI or bad path to jQueryUI or loading jQuery library more than once